# Add a wms layer to OL for Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, openlayers, gis

Just installed Openlayers 7.2 for Drupal 7. I have trouble figuring out how to make a wms layer that shows these info:

http://www.kulturstyrelsen.dk/fileadmin/_migrated/content_uploads/2_1_3_Beskrivelse_af_WMS_WFS_tjenester_01.pdf

I tried to create a standard wms layer, from the layer option and put : http://www.kulturarv.dk/ffpublic/wms/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities In the Base url, but nothing shows.

I tried to play with this in qgis. Inserted the same link as a WMS layer in Qgis, and this worked very well. What am i missing ? Is this the wrong way to approach it in OL ?

Comment: Try to use just : http://www.kulturarv.dk/ffpublic/wms/ows? or http://www.kulturarv.dk/ffpublic/wms/ows?service=wms (not sure)

Comment: Thanks, i just tried your suggestions, but no luck :(
No markers shows up.